# iOS UINavigationBar - When Large Title Text switches to Title Text

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

Is there an event that occurs when the Title Text of `UINavigationBar` switches from Large Title Text to Title Text?  I would like to change the text when the Title Text goes from large to regular.

Comment: Though I actually don't know if that is possible or not as of now, the intended behavior for the new large title is to put emphasis on the title itself so that it is clearly visible to the user. Large title was introduced so that the title **stands out** from other components. Therefore you should not try to use different titles for different appearances.

Comment: That's unfortunate.  When I scroll up, I get the title, truncated with three dots.  I guess I'll just have to come up with a smaller title.  Thanks.